# Dividing stream network of specified lengths in ArcGIS for Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, hydrology, linear-referencing

[image]

we are trying to find hydro power potential of river basin by using ArcGis and SWAT ,we have created stream network ,but unable to divide stream network at 500mts interval, unable to find the tool

Comment: You may want to investigate [Linear Referencing](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/guide-books/linear-referencing/what-is-linear-referencing.htm).

Comment: Does your network contain loops/bifurcation as this will be a problem?

Comment: Mr.Hornbydd our network contains small bifurcation

Comment: By "divide stream network at 500mts interval" do you mean split its lines every 500 meters, display 500 meter markers along it, or something else?  Either way would you be able to [edit] your question to let us know more about what you have researched/tried so far.  In particular, have you investigated linear referencing which I think is likely to be at least part of the solution.